# changing the name of pdf by the title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

In my application I obtain a title of `PDF` which is saved in my `plist` with static name which is i given like `s.pdf`

After that I find the title of that pdf and now I want to save the same pdf with that title name which I got and also replacing the old name which is s.pdf
So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably going to need **NSFileManager** `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`

> Copies the directory or file specified in a given path to a different location in the file system identified by another path.

Example *This is not a complete code it's for explanation only*:

```
// This will get you the Bundle Path.
NSString*path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

// This will get your PDF in the Bundle Path.
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"s" ofType:@"pdf"]

// Copy your file to the same destination but with different name. 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:OldFileNameInBundle 
                                    toPath:NewFileNameInBundle 
                                     error:&err]
```

[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a)